# Replacing blanks with Null in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, isnull

I am working on a Hive table on Hadoop and doing Data wrangling with PySpark. I read the dataset:

```
dt = sqlContext.sql('select * from  db.table1')
df.select("var1").printSchema()
|-- var1: string (nullable = true)
```

have some empty values in the dataset that Spark seems to be unable to recognize! I can easily find Null values by

```
df.where(F.isNull(F.col("var1"))).count()
10163101
```

but when I use

```
df.where(F.col("var1")=='').count()
```

it gives me zero however when I check in sql, I have 6908 empty values.

Here are SQL queries and their results:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [Y].[dbo].[table1]
where var1=''

6908
```

And

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [Y].[dbo].[table1]
where var1 is null

10163101
```

the counts for SQL and Pyspark table are the same:

```
df.count()
10171109
```

and

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM [Y].[dbo].[table1]
10171109
```

And when I try to find blanks by using length or size, I get an error:

```
dt.where(F.size(F.col("var1")) == 0).count()

AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'size(var1)' due to data type 
mismatch: argument 1 requires (array or map) type, however, 'var1' 
is of string type.;"
```

How should I address this issue? My Spark version is '1.6.3'

Thanks

Comment: @pault Updated the code. I know they are different but I don't know how Pyspark can recognize empty values!

Comment: Interesting- can you also include the code that shows how you read the table into the DataFrame and the output of `df.select("var1").printSchema()`? Maybe also check `df.count()` is the same as `select count(*) from [Y].[dbo].[table1]`. Finally try `df.where(F.size(F.col("var1")) == 0).count()`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried regexp and finally was able to find those blanks!!

```
dtnew = dt.withColumn('test',F.regexp_replace(F.col('var1') , '\s+|,',''))

dtnew.where(F.col('test')=='').count()
6908
```